# PHP Conditional dates treatment - comparing times & dates

Tags: php

I want to make a condition for my function to work. This is the logic.

Booking closing is 12noon today.
If the current time is before closing time(say 11am today) then run function x. I need to set a time when booking closes and compare it to the current time.

```
$tz_object = new DateTimeZone('Africa/Kampala');
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimezone($tz_object);
$timeNow = $datetime->format('Y\-m\-d\ h:i:s');

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTime(23,00);
$timeAllowed = $datetime->format('Y\-m\-d\ h:i:s');

if ($timeNow < $timeAllowed) {
    function woo_add_cart_fee() {

      global $woocommerce;

      $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Custom', 'woocommerce'), number_format(5) );

    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing DateTime objects is easy. You do not need to convert the date time to a string.

```
// time when booking closes
$bookclose = new \DateTime();
$bookclose->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Africa/Kampala'));
$bookclose->setTime(12,0,0);

// fake a time that the booking is being made for testing
$bookingtime = new \DateTime();
$bookingtime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Africa/Kampala'));

$bookingtime->setTime(11,59,59);
echo 'Booking time is ' . $bookingtime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
if ($bookingtime < $bookclose) {
    echo ' ALLOWED'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo ' NOT ALLOWED'.PHP_EOL;
}

$bookingtime->setTime(12,0,0);
echo 'Booking time is ' . $bookingtime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
if ($bookingtime < $bookclose) {
    echo ' ALLOWED'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo ' NOT ALLOWED'.PHP_EOL;
}

$bookingtime->setTime(12,0,1);
echo 'Booking time is ' . $bookingtime->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
if ($bookingtime < $bookclose) {
    echo ' ALLOWED'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo ' NOT ALLOWED'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

RESULTS:

```
Booking time is 19/01/2017 11:59:59 ALLOWED
Booking time is 19/01/2017 12:00:00 NOT ALLOWED
Booking time is 19/01/2017 12:00:01 NOT ALLOWED
```